# cant read a map created in while loop in another while loop

Tags: java

I am trying to create a map of objects inside a while loop and use it in other loops:

```
int x = 0;
    Map<String, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("(") == true) {
            StringTokenizer st;
            st = new StringTokenizer(line, "()");
            String noden = st.nextToken();
            int heu = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            x++;
            //System.out.println(noden + "=" + heu);
            map.put("n" + x, new Node(noden, heu));
        }
    }
```

I can access this map outside this loop and get the data stored in it, but when I am trying to use it in another while loop its empty:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("->") == true) {
            StringTokenizer st;
            st = new StringTokenizer(line, "-> ,");
            for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
            }
            String Source_node = st.nextToken();
            String Dest_node = st.nextToken();
            //System.out.println(Source_node + "->" + Dest_node);
            for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                Node n1 = map.get("n" + i);
                System.out.println(n1.value);
            }
            int eweight = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                Node n1 = map.get("n" + i);
                System.out.println(n1.value);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                Node node_source = map.get("n" + i);
                Node node_dest = map.get("n" + i);
                if (Source_node.equals(node_source.value)) {
                    if (Dest_node.equals(node_dest.value)) {
                        node_source.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                            new Edge(node_dest, eweight)
                        };
                        System.out.println(node_source.pos);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the whole method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int x = 0;
    Map<String, Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("(") == true) {
            StringTokenizer st;
            st = new StringTokenizer(line, "()");
            String noden = st.nextToken();
            int heu = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            x++;
            //System.out.println(noden + "=" + heu);
            map.put("n" + x, new Node(noden, heu));
        }
    }

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("->") == true) {
            StringTokenizer st;
            st = new StringTokenizer(line, "-> ,");
            for (Map.Entry<String, Node> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
            }
            String Source_node = st.nextToken();
            String Dest_node = st.nextToken();
            //System.out.println(Source_node + "->" + Dest_node);
            for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                Node n1 = map.get("n" + i);
                System.out.println(n1.value);
            }
            int eweight = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                Node n1 = map.get("n" + i);
                System.out.println(n1.value);
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                Node node_source = map.get("n" + i);
                Node node_dest = map.get("n" + i);
                if (Source_node.equals(node_source.value)) {
                    if (Dest_node.equals(node_dest.value)) {
                        node_source.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                            new Edge(node_dest, eweight)
                        };
                        System.out.println(node_source.pos);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: are both loops in the same method?

Comment: both loops are in main method

Comment: Are you sure you are not clearing the map in between the two loops?

Comment: print map size between two loops

Comment: there is nothing between the two loops , one ends the other starts

Comment: Could you post the entire method?

Comment: when i print the map between the loops i get the content

Comment: Do you make a new BufferedReader in between? Does it even enter the second while loop? Because after the first loop the BufferedReader already read all lines...

Comment: Could  you try adding `br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));` between the two loops?

Comment: so i should create a new bufferedReader for the second loop

Comment: Ok, I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program never even enters the second while loop, as the BufferedReader br already read all of the lines in the first loop. `br.readLine()` will therefore always return `null`.

A simple fix would be to create a new BufferedReader in between the two while loops.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"));
```

However, I would consider finding a different approach, because reading the same file twice is not optimal.